# Why does my shell script not find anything (find . -name script.sh | grep watermelon)

Tags: shell, grep

I have a script that I'm running from the home directory to search for all files called "script.sh" that contain the string "watermelon". It's not finding anything but I can clearly see these scripts in the subdirectories. Could someone please suggest a change to the command I'm using:

```
find . -name script.sh | grep watermelon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use xargs:

```
find . -name script.sh | xargs grep watermelon
```

xargs will modify the behavior to search within the files, rather than just search within the names of the files.

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns the filename it finds by default. If you want it to search within the files then you need to pipe it to `xargs` or use the `-exec` and `-print` predicates:

```
find . -name script.sh -exec grep -q watermelon {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

use `-type f` to indicate file

```
find . -type f -name "script.sh" -exec grep "watermelon" "{}" +;
```

or if you have bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -Rl "watermelon" **/script.sh
```